# Type to byte array conversion in Swift

Tags: generics, swift, serialization

I need the byte representation of a given type, especially `double`, `float`, `int8`, etc.

```
typealias Byte = UInt8

enum ByteOrder {
    case BigEndian
    case LittleEndian
}

func pack<T>(var value: T, byteOrder: ByteOrder) -> [Byte] {
    let valueByteArray = withUnsafePointer(&value) {
        Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<Byte>($0), count: sizeof(T)))
    }
    return (byteOrder == .LittleEndian) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()
}

func unpack<T>(valueByteArray: [Byte], toType type: T.Type, byteOrder: ByteOrder) -> T {
    let bytes = (byteOrder == .LittleEndian) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()
    return UnsafePointer<T>(bytes).memory
}
```

What do you think?

Especially I am interested in your opinion on

- [CFByteOrder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFByteOrder) does offer already a byte order, but I decided to go with a different definition.
- We can use the type inference and get rid of `forType type: T.Type`, which works fine for

  ```
  let result: double = unpack(someArray, .LittleEndian)
  ```

  but fails for

  ```
  let result = unpack(someArray, .LittleEndian)
  ```
- Is the following nicer? I don't think so, but what about you. :-)

  ```
  func unpack<T>(valueByteArray: [Byte], byteOrder: ByteOrder) -> T {
      let bytes = (byteOrder == .LittleEndian) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()    
      return bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
          return UnsafePointer<T>($0.baseAddress).memory
      }
  }
  ```
- What do you think about encapsulating the two function in a class, e.g. `ByteBackPacker` and convert them to class functions?
- What about giving `byteOrder: ByteOrder` a default value, e.g. `.LittleEndian`, because this is the native byte order in iOS and Mac OS X, the primary platforms for Swift, I assume?

**Update:**
I created a [ByteBackpacker project on github](https://github.com/michaeldorner/ByteBackpacker). Let me know what you think about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a dedicated enumeration type `ByteOrder` is a good idea.
`CFByteOrder` is (ultimately) a type alias for `Int`, so you can
assign arbitrary integers to it, not just `CFByteOrderBig/LittleEndian`.

---

If you don't pass the type in the unpack function then the compiler
has to infer it from the context and either of these would work:

```
let d1 = unpack(bytes, byteOrder: .BigEndian) as Double
let d2 : Double = unpack(bytes, byteOrder: .BigEndian)
```

If you pass the type as an argument then the compiler infers
the return type:

```
let d3 = unpack(bytes, toType: Double.self, byteOrder: .BigEndian)
```

I think it is a matter of taste which version you choose, I would
prefer passing the type explicitly.

---

Encapsulating the functions into a type is also a good idea.
But I would use a `struct` which is initialized with the byte order,
and make that instance methods and not class methods. The reason
is that you probably will do several calls with the same byte order
and you don't have to pass it to every call:

```
struct BytePacker {
    let byteOrder : ByteOrder

    init (byteOrder: ByteOrder) {
        self.byteOrder = byteOrder
    }

    func pack<T>(var value: T) -> [Byte] { ... }
    func unpack<T>(valueByteArray: [Byte], toType type: T.Type) -> T { ... }
}
```

which can be used as

```
let packer = BytePacker(byteOrder: .BigEndian)
let bytes = packer.pack(12.34)
let d = packer.unpack(bytes, toType: Double.self)
```

---

There is a problem with

```
return UnsafePointer<T>(bytes).memory
```

in your first version of `unpack()` because is not guaranteed that the
elements of a Swift `Array` are stored in contiguous memory.

```
return bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    return UnsafePointer<T>($0.baseAddress).memory
}
```

as in your second version of `unpack()` is the correct solution
because `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` calls the block with a pointer to contiguous
storage.

---

Your code assumes that the host byte order is little-endian,
which is the case for all current OS X and iOS platforms.
On the other hand, Swift is open source now and people already start
to port it to different platforms. I have no idea if Swift will be
ported to a big-endian platform at some time.

I would at least make that assumption explicit by defining

```
enum ByteOrder {
    case BigEndian
    case LittleEndian

    static var hostByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian
}
```

and then replace

```
return (byteOrder == .LittleEndian) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()
```

by

```
return (byteOrder == ByteOrder.hostByteOrder) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()
```

In addition, I would add an assertion

```
assert(UInt(littleEndian: 1) == 1)
```

e.g. to the `init` method of `BytePacker`.

Alternatively, you can determine the actual host byte order at
runtime:

```
enum ByteOrder {
    case BigEndian
    case LittleEndian

    static var hostByteOrder = ByteOrder()

    init() {
        self = (UInt(littleEndian: 1) == 1) ? .LittleEndian : .BigEndian
    }
}
```

but I don't know if that is worth the hassle. (Note that 
the static property `hostByteOrder` is computed only once in 
the lifetime of the app, not each time that it is used.)

---

Your generic pack/unpack functions can be called with 
arguments of *any* type, and that would give wrong results or crashes for

- reference types, where the instance is just a pointer to the object,
- "complex types" like `Array` or `String`, which are a `struct` but
  use opaque pointers to the actual memory holding the elements.

There is – as far as I know – no protocol which comprises all integer and
floating point types. What you *could* do is to define a protocol

```
protocol PackableType { }
```

and make all types which can safely be packed and unpacked explicitly conform to it:

```
extension Int : PackableType { }
extension UInt16 : PackableType { }
// More integer types ...

extension Double : PackableType { }
// More floating point types ...
```

(Unfortunately, there are many integer types and I don't know if the repetition
can be avoided.)

Now you can restrict the type `<T>` to `<T : PackableType>`.
Alternatively, take a different approach and make the pack/unpack
methods operate on the type itself by defining a protocol extension:

```
extension PackableType {

    func pack(byteOrder byteOrder: ByteOrder) -> [Byte] {
        var value = self
        let valueByteArray = withUnsafePointer(&value) {
            Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<Byte>($0), count: sizeofValue(value)))
        }
        return (byteOrder == ByteOrder.hostByteOrder) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()
    }

    static func unpack(valueByteArray: [Byte], byteOrder: ByteOrder) -> Self {
        let bytes = (byteOrder == ByteOrder.hostByteOrder) ? valueByteArray : valueByteArray.reverse()
        return bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
            return UnsafePointer($0.baseAddress).memory
        }
    }
}
```

(Note how the compiler infers the type in `return UnsafePointer($0.baseAddress).memory`
automatically.)

This would now be used as

```
let bytes = 12.34.pack(byteOrder: .LittleEndian)
let double = Double.unpack(bytes, byteOrder: .LittleEndian)
```

and solve your question "how to define the return type in unpack" in a 
different way.

Comment: There is one dangerous thing you should change. `sizeofValue(value)` (which is now `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:)`) should be `MemoryLayout<Self>.size`. The thing is, if you cast to `PackableType` and execute `pack(byteOrder:)` you'll get a wrong result. For instance `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: UInt8(0) as Any)` is 32 bytes instead of what you would expect.

Comment: @DevAndArtist: Thank you for the feedback. Note that conformance to PackableType is (intentionally) declared explicitly for all "simple" types (like integers and floating point values) which can safely be byte-copied to an array and back. You cannot call the pack method on `UInt8(0) as Any`.

Comment: That's correct but if you'd try `([1, 0.5] as [PackageType]).map { $0.pack(byteOrder: .littleEndian) }` you'll get an array of two arrays of bytes, but these two array will be 40 bytes long each. The result is clearly not what you'd expect ;)

Comment: @DevAndArtist: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce. `([1, 0.5, UInt16(0x1234), Float(0.5)] as [PackableType]).map { $0.pack(byteOrder: .LittleEndian) }` gives `[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224, 63], [52, 18], [0, 0, 0, 63]]` with above code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, forget about my last example. I run into that problem I mentioned yesterday, because in my codebase I'm reusing the global generic function that converts `T` to `[Byte]`. It seems like from within an extension we're getting the correct size of `Self`. http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5815aec90a78bb5651913186 At the bottom when I just the bare function you'll see the wrong result I meant. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working my way through Martin's very useful answer. I have discovered one small simplification. The  ByteOrder enum is not required. NSHostByteOrder can be used:

```
var bigEndian = true
if (NSHostByteOrder() == NS_LittleEndian) {
    bigEndian = false
}
```

Comment: I am not completely sure, if this is a good idea, because the enum `NSByteOrder` has three entries: 
`enum NSByteOrder {NS_UnknownByteOrder, NS_LittleEndian, NS_BigEndian};`. Are we sure that `NS_UnknownByteOrder` will never happen?

Comment: The enumeration is also used as an argument to the pack method to specify the destination byte order.